# Why can I log and alert value returned from jQuery.width() but can't use in assignment?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm simply trying to total the widths of elements before a certain element index and assign that to a variable. I get NaN when using $(this).width() or $(object).width. Yet I can log and alert these numeric values fine?

Mark-up

```
    <div class="gallery">
        <div class="gallery-imgs" style="color: #000;">
            <div class="gallery-img-slide">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/700x1080">
            </div><div class="gallery-img-slide">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/900x1080">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function focusSlide(slide_index) {
debugger;

var offset_width;

if (slide_index === 0) {
    $(".gallery-imgs").css("margin-left",
        ($(".gallery").width() / 2) - $(".gallery-imgs").children().eq(slide_index).width() / 2 + "px");
}
else {
    $(".gallery-imgs").children().each(function(index, object){
        debugger;
        if (index < slide_index) {
            offset_width += $(object).width();
            console.log($(object).width());
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: `offset_width` is `undefined` at init, and `undefined + Number`=> `NaN`

Comment: @Kaiido thank you for the extra insight into why this happens. Useful information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you have `var offset_width;`.

You need to initialize it to a number like this: `var offset_width = 0;`

`offset_width += 1` really means `offset_width = offset_width + 1`.

If you do not set it to anything, that is an invalid statement because you are adding `NaN + 1`.  Your error is not actually because of `$(object).width()`

Comment: It's a purple number without quotes in developer tools. Definitely a number because I could use Math.round on it.

Comment: Thank you for the correct answer, I will take more care in initializing variables from now on.